# PHP adding gibberish to strings passed into mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, logging

in PHP, I'm using `mysql_query($querystring)` to insert some information into a table.

However, when I look at the MySQL Query Logs, it shows that gibberish is getting added:

MySQL Log:

```
INSERT INTO database.table 
SET
`col1` = '0^@0^@:^@0^@0^@:^@1^@8',
`col2` = '3^@8^@0',
`col3` = '3^@6^@8',
`col4` = '1^@2'
```

When I do a var_dump() on $querystring, everything looks fine, no ^@ are appended.

PHP var_dump() - Note: I just made up the 333 number.

```
string(333) "INSERT INTO database.table 
SET
`col1` = '00:00:18',
`col2` = '380',
`col3` = '368',
`col4` = '12'"
```

However, the MySQL logs are showing the ^@.  Is there any way to strip the ^@ from the $querystring?

The values stored in the database are '00:00:00' (the default value for that field), '3', '3', and '1'. Col1 is of type date, and Col2-4 are smallint(5).

Comment: The original code has a "," after `col1` = '00:00:18' , so no, it's not a missing comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a Encoding Issue.

Fix:

```
$string_input_to_mysql_query = iconv("UCS-2", "ISO-8859-1", $string_input_to_mysql_query);
```

Answer (score 2):

What exactly happens to the table?
Maybe you just forgot the "," after `col1` = '00:00:18' ?

Comment: failing that, i suspect the field type he's inserting into is something bizarre

Comment: My bad, just forgot the "," when typing the post.

Comment: Is there an error happening? If not, what is the content of the table after executing the statement? Please check your field types as Kerin suggested.

Comment: No error, the content in the table is col1 = 00:00:00 (default value), col2 = 3, col3 = 3, col4 = 1. They are all column type smallint(5) except for the date column.

Comment: Are you sure the lengths of your fields are declared right? I've tested the statement and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, the fields are declared right.  If you execute the SQL query in something like MySQL admin, it works just fine.  The original values, '00:00:18','380','368', and '12' come from .csv file that I process in PHP,and somewhere along the line it's picking up gibberish characters. Kind of like how if you sometimes paste from MS Word into a textarea, it looks fine in the textarea box, but extra characters are added in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your field type is `VARCHAR`, or at least `INT` for numbers.  `MySQL` could be messing with your strings to make them fit an unfit type.

Comment: They are all smallint(5) except for the date column. I tried setting them to varchar and int, and I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix I ended up using:

```
/* 
        Strip hidden gibberish characters inherited from the original .csv file
        NOTE: Do a var_dump() to check for hidden gibberish characters, compare the string length from the var_dump() to an eye count of the character length that shows on the screen. Also, check MySQL Query Log to see what characters are being added during INSERT
*/

    for($j=0; $j<strlen( $Parts[$i]);$j++)
    {
        if(is_numeric($Parts[$i][$j]) or $Parts[$i][$j]==':' or $Parts[$i][$j]=='.')
        $stringholder.=$Parts[$i][$j];
    }
    $Parts[$i] = $stringholder;
    $stringholder ="";
```

Not the cleanest, but gets the job done.